# Where can I find a complete documentation of the symfony2 bundle KayueWordpressBundle

Tags: php, wordpress, symfony

I'm trying to create a Wordpress custom backend using Symfony2 framework, after googling the question I found this bundle [KayueWordpressBundle](https://github.com/kayue/KayueWordpressBundle) it works fine.

But, where can I find a complete documentation or just a kind of guide of features which the bundle contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, I'm afraid the only documentation available is the file `README.md`, available in the [github page link](https://github.com/kayue/KayueWordpressBundle). The code is also (most of the times) easy to read, and comes with comments, providing documentation within the code itself.

Hopefully the author will deliver a more detailed documentation page soon :)